# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-193]

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Can AnyOne tell me What wrong with my code

### HibernateConfig

```
package com.app.EcommerceBackend.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.app.EcommerceBackend.dto"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    // Change the below based on the DBMS you choose
    private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/ecommerce";
    private final static String DATABASE_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private final static String DATABASE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
    private final static String DATABASE_USERNAME = "sa";
    private final static String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";

    // dataSource bean will be available
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        // Providing the database connection information
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);


        return dataSource;

    }

    // sessionFactory bean will be available

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        builder.scanPackages("com.app.EcommerceBackend.dto");

        return builder.buildSessionFactory();

    }



    // All the hibernate properties will be returned in this method 
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();


        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", DATABASE_DIALECT);      
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");


        return properties;
    }

    // transactionManager bean
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }


}
```

### CategoryTestCase

```
package com.app.EcommerceBackend.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.app.EcommerceBackend.dao.CategoryDAO;
import com.app.EcommerceBackend.dto.Category;

public class CategoryTestCase {

    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    private static CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

    private Category category;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws Exception
    {
        org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer().start();

        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.app.EcommerceBackend");
        context.refresh();
        categoryDAO = (CategoryDAO) context.getBean("categoryDAO");
    }



    @Test
    public void testCRUDcategory()
    {
        //Adding operation
        category = new Category();

        category.setName("Mobile");
        category.setDescription("This is some description for Mobile!");
        category.setImageURL("MOB01.png");

        assertEquals("Successfully added a category inside the table!", true, categoryDAO.add(category));

        category = new Category();

        category.setName("Television");
        category.setDescription("This is some description for Television!");
        category.setImageURL("TEL02.png");

        assertEquals("Successfully added a category inside the table!", true, categoryDAO.add(category));

        //Fetching and Updating  Category
        category=categoryDAO.get(2);
        category.setName("TV");
        assertEquals("Successfully updated a single category in the table!", true, categoryDAO.update(category));

        //Deleting A category
        category=categoryDAO.get(1);
        assertEquals("Successfully deleted a single category in the table!", true, categoryDAO.delete(category));

        //Fetching the List
        /*assertEquals("Successfully fetched the list of category from the table!", 1, categoryDAO.list().size());*/
    }

}
```

### Getting Error

> ```
>   HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>     Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>      org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
> ```
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
>   (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect: localhost" [90067-193])
>     org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
>     org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
>     org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>     org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
>
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken:
>   "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost"
>   [90067-193]
>     org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>     org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
>     org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:452)
>     org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:329)     org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:115)
>     org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:99)
>     org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)

### You can also check my gitHub code https://github.com/sunilgit1/ECommerce

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of h2 database engine you're running.
And make sure that the version of h2 in your pom.xml file is same. If not change it to the same version.

If the h2 database engine is 1.4.196, then the dependency you are adding through pom.xml for h2 database driver should be also 1.4.196.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that , for H2 to work with tcp , you need to start H2 in server mode

to start the server in server mode , you need to create a TCP server , so below configuration will give you connetion for 1 application.

```
import org.h2.tools.Server;

     @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
        public Server h2Server1() throws SQLException {
            return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9080");
        }
```

if you want more applications to connect to same H2 server with TCP , you need to add one more instance to it - with different port

```
 // Second App
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server h2Server2() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9081");
    }
```